# Attach a onClick Listener to Epoxy Controller Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to attach an Onclick Listener to my TypedEpoxyController .

```
 override fun buildModels(data: List<BookView>) {



    data.forEach { bookView ->
        bookItem {
            id(System.currentTimeMillis())
            bookName(bookView.name)




        }



    }




}
interface BookSelectListener {
    fun onSelected(books: BookView)
}}
```

When I implement the on click listener nothing is happening. When i click on the recyler item. Please help me.